# Creating a model, getting an error: undefined function put_flash

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am following along in this tutorial, and I'm working on the create function.  **It can't seem to find the put_flash message?**

Also, can someone clarify what "alias Rumbl.User" does?

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model
  alias Rumbl.User

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do 
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name username), [])
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20) 
  end   

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    {:ok, user} = Repo.insert(changeset)

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.name} created!") 
    |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
  end
end
```

**Update**

My web.ex looks like:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Web do
  @moduledoc """
  A module that keeps using definitions for controllers,
  views and so on.

  This can be used in your application as:

      use Rumbl.Web, :controller
      use Rumbl.Web, :view

  The definitions below will be executed for every view,
  controller, etc, so keep them short and clean, focused
  on imports, uses and aliases.

  Do NOT define functions inside the quoted expressions
  below.
  """

  def model do

    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query
    end
  end

  def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller

      alias Rumbl.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Query

      import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
      import Rumbl.Gettext
    end
  end

  def view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates"

      # Import convenience functions from controllers
      import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]

      # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
      use Phoenix.HTML

      import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
      import Rumbl.ErrorHelpers
      import Rumbl.Gettext
    end
  end

  def router do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Router
    end
  end

  def channel do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Channel

      alias Rumbl.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Query
      import Rumbl.Gettext
    end
  end

  @doc """
  When used, dispatch to the appropriate controller/view/etc.
  """
  defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
    apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
  end
end
```

Comment: I know `alias Rumbl.User` is short for `alias Rumbl.User, as: User`. Omitting the as: x part basically takes the last part of the module name. Can't help you with the other one though.

Comment: Please provide more detail on "It can't seem to find the put_flash message?". If you are getting a compile error, please include it in your question. `put_flash` is part of the `Phoenix.Controller` module. This module should be imported in the `def controller do` block in `web/web.ex` and gets imported by `use Rumbl.Web, :model`.

Comment: To add to @Robert comment, `alias` allows you to access a module by a shorter name. By default it uses the last module name. So `alias Rumpl.User` allows you to access that module by `User`. You can override the alias with the option `as: OtherName`. For example `alias MyApp.Blogs.Post`, as: P` would then allow `P.changeset(...)`

Comment: @StevePallen I added my web.ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with our `def create` function. This should be part of your controller. It does not belong in the model/schema. The reason your getting the error is that Phoenix.Controller is not imported for model. Note the `def controller do` block in your `web.ex` file. It has a `use Phoenix.Controller` call. This is where the `put_flash` function will get imported.

Move the `create` function to your controller.

The flow/lifecycle of the web request is

> webserver => endpoint => router => controller => view => template

The `Plug.Conn` (conn) struct is the data that flows through the web request and is transformed through the use of `Plugs`.

In side your controller, you use the Repo and ultimately the schema to access the database.

The `conn` struct should never be passed to your schema. It violates separation of concerns.

Comment: btw, how can I tell what version of phoenix I have locally?

Comment: look in your mix.lock file in the project root folder. It shows the versions of all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!!